# What is the Idc to Iac(rms) multiplication factor for these two power supply configurations

Tags: power-supply, current

[image: Title]

For each linear dc power supply configuration, when designing the power supply, in order to size the power rating of the required transformer correctly we need to know the supply's dc output current to transformer ac rms output current multiplication factor.

I know the multiplication factors (ratios) for the following three power supply configurations...

[image: PSUs]

But, my question, what are the multiplication factors (ratios) for the following two power supply configurations?

[image: PSUs]

I assume it would be possible to calculate these values, perhaps using integration, but I don't know how to do that.

I am not actually currently designing a PSU but I'd just like to know what these values are for future reference.

Comment: That will depend on your capacitor size. Small capacitor, less peak current and hence lower RMS current but also higher ripple so you need more voltage headroom for your linear regulator which in turn means more losses. You are basically trading transformer losses for regulator losses, but there is a minimum in between. But unanswerable without known capacitance, or capacitance to load current factor.

Comment: In simple terms, comparing a half wave to a full wave rectified output, to deliver the same power you need \$\sqrt2\$ more current for half wave. But, to make it more complicated, you need more reservoir capacitance to prevent the ripple exceeding limits that cause the regulator output to become impaired. Why not use a simulator?

Answer (score 1):

The Idc to Irms multiplication factors for all the shown versions of PSU are, for practical purposes, independent of the size of the filter capacitor. The Idc to Irms multiplication factors can, for practical purposes, be taken to be a constant within the range of filter capacitances that would be employed within a practical power supply. The multiplication factors for PSU1 and PSU3 (see below) are well known and well publicised values and are always quoted without specifying the size of the filter capacitor.

After some thought I have now sorted this one out. The nougat of information which I needed was provided by Andy when he commented "comparing a half wave to a full wave rectified output, to deliver the same power you need sqrt(2) more current for half wave." I had not previously realised this. - Thanks very much Andy.

[image: PSUs]

Going from PSU1 to PSU2 is moving from a full-wave rectifier to a half-wave rectifier and so the multiplication factor goes up by sqrt(2). 1.75 * sqrt(2) = 2.47.

Going from PSU2 to PSU3 is moving from a half-wave rectifier to two half-wave rectifiers, each one half-wave rectifying on alternate half-cycles and so, to provide the same load current we divide 2.47 by 2 = 1.23. The same load current is being sourced from the transformer over both positive and negative half cycles rather than just positive half cycles as in PSU2.

Going from PSU1 to PSU4. Both circuits are full-wave rectifiers, current is flowing in the transformer in both positive and negative half cycles. The difference between these two PSUs is that in PSU4, the rectification, on each half cycle, is only charging half the filter capacitance. This means that to get the same load current, as that in PSU1, the transformer's rms current must double in order to provide the same amount of charge to the total filter capacitance as is provided by the rectifier in PSU1. So the multiplication factor becomes 1.75 x 2 = 3.5.

I tried to find out these multiplication factors some years ago. I purchased a true rms clamp meter to measure the transformer's secondary rms current, built the circuits and the results I obtained were very close to those which the theory above gives.

Comment: Please show _”independent of the size of the filter capacitors”_ by simulating the circuits with first very large capacitor then very small. If you ignore that you will loose regulation in the later case, then perhaps the transformer RMS current holds true but your Iout won’t.

Comment: @winny Perhaps you could implement and post the relevant simulations if you require them. Obviously you would need to keep the ripple on the capacitor low enough to maintain enough regulator header voltage to maintain regulation.

Comment: I have them, but I see an issue with the capacitor size being independent since it’s not. It’s also a design choice to make them larger than absolutely necessary to simply move losses from the linear regulator, which usually comes with hard limits on voltage and power dissipation, to the transformer by choosing to have more copper losses in the transformer by lowering the secondary number of turns.

Comment: @winny I've read and reread your comment. Sorry, I don't understand it. Increasing the size of the filter capacitor will reduce ripple voltage which will increase losses in the regulator.

Comment: Yes. And by doing increasing the capacitor you have the option to decrease the number of secondary turns, saving losses in your regulator due to less voltage across it. Irms is now higher due to higher peak current but Plinear is lower. Do the opposite and the opposite happens. It’s a tradeoff. Since your linear regulator has a hard limit on max voltage it can accept, there is an upper bound for this. Henceforth, the capacitor size plays a big role here and it’s not independent. Your original problem statement is more complex than you might realize.

Comment: @winny Whether or not the losses in the regulator are lower or higher with reduced ripple voltage and reduced secondary voltage is a separate issue and a distraction  away from the question of whether or not secondary rms current varies with filter capacitor value. If the capacitor increases in value then the charging current is higher but the ripple voltage is smaller, making the time taken to charge the capacitor smaller (current flows for less time). Wouldn't the increase in charging current be cancelled out by the reduction in charging time keeping the secondary rms current constant?

Comment: No, higher peak = higher RMS = more transformer winding heating. Sure, energy supplied total is similar, but my main point is that you have a narrow window of capacitance you can select for a real application and it will have an impact so I still believe your first paragraph about capacitor size is wrong. If all you care about is transformer and diode losses, zero capacitance will give you best performance in all example circuits you gave.

Comment: The question asked about AC current RMS. This and no output inductor I interpreted as sine (voltage) wave.

Comment: @winny The current in the transformer's secondary will be short pulses. The short current pulses are delivered at the peaks of the secondary's sine voltage waveform during the short periods of time when the capacitor is charging. Even so, the current rating of the transformer is specified as an rms value.

Comment: Yes, so AC it is. Set your capacitance to zero and you will have minimal Irms/Idc ratio.

Comment: @winny See edit, I hope that's better.

Comment: Much better! Thank you.